# Como retornar um número como se fosse uma data?

Tags: python, funções, data

Receber a data no formato texto dd/mm/yyyy e devolver a data no formato número yyyymmdd (exemplo: receba “05/10/1983” e retorne 19831005). Mas apresentou um erro na sintaxe.

```
def data(i):
     dia=i[0:2]
     mes=i[3:5]
     ano=i[6:]
     novadata = int(''".join([ano,mes,dia]))
      return novadata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceto pelo fato da função ser complexa demais, o único problema é que tem um aspas duplas ali logo depois das duas aspas simples colocada como separador para o `join()`.

Também há um problema conceitual em transformar isto em inteiro, este valor não é numérico, até funciona, mas ele não representa uma quantidade, pelo menos não de forma apropriada, não pode fazer conta com ele porque teria regras especiais para dar certo, não use dados quantitativos para isto. Pode ser que este problema seja sintoma de algum erro maior ainda, não sei nem se a data deveria estar sendo tratada desta forma.

```
def data(i):
    return int(''.join([i[6:], i[3:5], i[0:2]]))
print(data('05/10/1983'))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EaSDK6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FormatDate). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/FormatDate.py).